# In Oracle APEX, how do I make my button delete a row?

Tags: oracle-apex

In Oracle APEX, I figured out how to add a button into the APEX table.  Here is my table so far, and the extra column has a link "Sample Link Text"   .

[image]

It is by adding this code :

```
<button class="t-Button  " id="#edit_link#" 
 onclick="showRow(#edit_link#);" type="button"><span class="t-Button-label">   + </span></button>
```

However, I'm stuck on the task of causing the button click to delete the current row. How do I link the button to an action (like delete or update)?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a created that Apex table as a tabular form, I believe that there's a default delete button that comes with it but if there's none, here's how to create a delete button:

Under the region of your table, create a button. Then set it's "Action" property to "Redirect to URL". Set it's target URL to this `javascript:apex.confirm(htmldb_delete_message,'MULTI_ROW_DELETE');`

Then Save.

Comment: When I added in this code, it puts the button . However , it doesn't actually delete any row (or even bring up a prompt to delete a specific row ) . any clue on that ? thanks

Comment: @Coffee: just wondering if my answer really worked since "it doesn't actually delete any row " according to your last comment

Comment: correct - it didn't work. but you got me on track. I'll be working on more tomorrow (stepped away for a few days, as other work came up). i'll let u know thx

Answer (score 0):

Also Please check if the Delete check box is selected in process.
[Property Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAHcR.png)